Range exclusion function
I have a range of lines in a text file defined by the start and end line number (inclusive) of the range (e.g. (1, 200)).
I would like to to exclude some other line ranges from this main range (e.g. (9, 20), (101, 103) might be "forbidden").
After excluding the forbidden ranges, what ranges do I have left? In this case, it should be (1, 8), (21, 100), and (104, 200).

The task also analogs to:

I originally have an entire month of free time starting January 1st ((1, 31))
But I have some commitments too, that span several days (e.g. (2, 3), (10, 17), etc.)
What periods of free time do I have left?


I've made a couple functions in Python to answer this kind of question:
Interval = tuple[int, int]
"""Intervals are inclusive, the start and end are considered to be part of the interval"""


def exclude(intervals: list[Interval], interval: Interval) -> list[Interval]:
    """Exclude an interval from a set of intervals

    This function takes a list of intervals and an interval to exclude from them. For each interval in the 
    list, it removes the parts that overlap with the exclusion interval, effectively "subtracting" the 
    exclusion interval from each. The resulting non-overlapping intervals are returned.

    Args:
        intervals (list[Interval]): A sorted list of disjoint (start, end) tuples.
        interval (Interval): A (start, end) tuple representing the interval to exclude.

    Returns:
        list[Interval]: A list of intervals with the specified sub-interval excluded.

    Examples:
        >>> exclude([(0, 10)], (3, 5))
        [(0, 2), (6, 10)]

        >>> exclude([(0, 3), (6, 10)], (3, 6))
        [(0, 2), (7, 10)]

        >>> exclude([(0, 3), (6, 10)], (9, 10))
        [(0, 3), (6, 8)]

        >>> exclude([(0, 3), (6, 10)], (7, 8))
        [(0, 3), (6, 6), (9, 10)]
    """
    new_intervals = []
    start_exclude, end_exclude = interval

    for start, end in intervals:
        start, end = start, end
        if end < start_exclude or start > end_exclude:
            new_intervals.append((start, end))
        else:
            if start < start_exclude:
                new_intervals.append((start, start_exclude - 1))
            if end > end_exclude:
                new_intervals.append((end_exclude + 1, end))

    return new_intervals


def exclude_all_of(intervals: list[Interval], excludes: list[Interval]) -> list[Interval]:
    """Exclude each of the exclude intervals from the list of allowed intervals

    Args:
        intervals (list[Interval]): A sorted list of disjoint (start, end) tuples.
        excludes (list[Interval]): An unsorted list of (start, end) intervals to exclude.

    Returns:
        list[Interval]: A list of intervals with the specified sub-intervals excluded.

    Examples:
        >>> exclude_all_of([(0, 10)], [(0, 1), (3, 6), (0, 2), (5, 7)])
        [(8, 10)]
        >>> exclude_all_of([(0, 10)], [(0, 1), (5, 6), (3, 3), (8, 9)])
        [(2, 2), (4, 4), (7, 7), (10, 10)]
    """
    if not excludes:
        return intervals
    interval, *rest = excludes
    intervals = exclude(intervals, interval)
    return exclude_all_of(intervals, rest)



I would like to make the exclude_all_of function as fast as possible, so I'm most interested in feedback about algorithm/implementation choice.
At the moment I think exclude_all_of is O(mn+n(n-1)/2), m = len(intervals) n = len(excludes). So polynomial time, O(n^2).
Is this a good approach for this type of, range-exclusion task?

Convert all the intervals into tuples (start_time, 1) and (end_time, -1). Sort them by time. Compute the cumulative sum of the second elements. Collect the intervals where the sum is 0. The time complexity is linearithmic.

@vnp that's really clever, thanks. Is this a well-known named technique? how do you find out about such algorithms?

@vnp I've written an implementation of that that seems to work, but I have no idea why it works. Is that also the kind of question I am allowed to ask on this site?

representation
The OP considers just integers,
but more generally we might consider an interval like
"positive reals less than \$\pi\$".

"""Intervals are inclusive,

Thank you for being explicit, that's very helpful.
In the python ecosystem it would be more natural to talk about
a half-open [start, end) range(), which excludes the end value.
Over in SQL land this shows up as ... WHERE start <= x AND x < end,
and we need that notation if x is a real number.
A half-open interval like that will compose with others, and is quite different
from a [start, end] closed interval like WHERE x BETWEEN start AND end.
This has a quite noticeable effect on a series of queries like

home prices from $200k to $300k
home prices from $300k to $400k

where a $300k listing will regrettably appear in both query results.
I like it when f(g(x)) functions compose nicely, and also
when queries compose nicely.
For the rest of this, let's make the "int vs real" distinction go away.
We can always gather up and sort the various real number breakpoints,
perhaps inserting \$\pm \,\epsilon\$,
map them to ordinal rankings, and talk about them that way,
mapping back to reals as needed.
redundant assign
This changes nothing.
        start, end = start, end

Simply delete it.
complexity
The repeated \$O(n)\$ linear for start, end in intervals: scan
is slower than necessary.
Suppose we have interval size \$\ll\$ number of intervals.
Then set() offers a very simple way to efficiently remove
excluded regions, with space and time complexity proportional to
total time span:
>>> set(range(7))
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> 
>>> set(range(7)) - set(range(2, 4)) - set(range(3, 5))
{0, 1, 5, 6}

OTOH we might have some intervals that are "large",
for example with one bearing a label of "The Hundred Years War",
comprised of more than \$36,500\$ elements.
In that case we would prefer to handle each exclusion split
in \$O(\log n)\$ logarithmic time.
Put a bunch of inclusive 2-tuples (or ranges) into a
sorted container.
When processing each exclusion, exploit binary search
to quickly identify the split location.
Delete one range and insert a pair of new ranges.
recursion vs iteration
Your exclude() helper is forced to make a copy of all
the included intervals we have encountered so far.
This is suboptimal. An iterative
2-way merge sort
could avoid lots of redundant work.
doctests
The >>> doctests
are beautiful, and I thank you for them!
It seems clear that you verified with $ python -m doctest *.py,
as they run flawlessly.

How expensive is it to turn a list into a set though?

I've thought about using bisect to find the intersecting intervals, but what if the exclude interval completely overlaps many "allowed" intervals?
